# Can we create custom field and roll up that information to another field in Rally

Tags: rally

Sum up all the Effort field (Custom Field) scored for each Epic under a Feature and push it to the Value field in the Feature. The AC/PPM integration will then automatically push that to PPM (Agile Score).

Comment: Please provide some more info, some code snippet  etc..

Comment: We are still using the User story work item but have named it as Epic as they have Epics under feature in their taxonomy.....Effort to them is at Epic level which is just a random number from the scale of 1-10  which the customer uses internally  ....the whole Idea what I are trying to prove them is the ability to get sum of all the effort calculated from the custom field (effort) to roll-up to feature

Comment: Havent started working on the code....still learning tim and looking for the reference code which can help me to deliver customer requirment

Comment: This is not possible without doing the programming yourself. You could take a look at the portfolio cost app (https://github.com/RallyTechServices/portfolio-cost-apps) as a reference.